# parse contents of PHP Curl

Tags: php, parsing, curl

I'm fairly new to PHP(early entry-level) . I am curling a web page in php. However I need a variable.

In the terminal, I curl the page to a txt file. The text file is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="studentid" value="23019bdisakd" /></form>
```

I need 23019bdisakd from that. In the terminal I do the following:

```
grep "studentid" | tr -d '\"' | cut -d"=" -f4 | cut -d"/" -f1 | tr -d '\n' ;
```

and it can do it.

However, now I need to do it in the PHP

What I have:

```
 $url = "www.hereisthewebpage.com";
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $lines = curl_exec ($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);
```

I did some research and found parse_str(). How would I use that?
I concocted the following:
$StudentID= lines | grep "wosid" | tr -d '\"' | cut -d"=" -f4 | cut -d"/" -f1 | tr -d '\n' ; 
but I'm 99% this is not the right way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried already to complete your homework (aside from posting here)?

Comment: well i'm a bit unsure if the grep, cut, and tr are allowed within php

Comment: my apache would say i have a parse error (not sure which part of the syntax in $StudentID= lines | grep "wosid" | tr -d '\"' | cut -d"=" -f4 | cut -d"/" -f1 | tr -d '\n' ; is incorrect
or rather if the | are even allowed...

Comment: Did you read the [\documentation for `parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with a regex.

something along the lines of

```
$pattern = '/value="([a-zA-Z0-9]*)"/';
preg_match($pattern, $lines, $matches);

$studentId = $matches[0];
```

Comment: Oh!
awesome
i didn't know about preg_match. thanks for that!